# git log -S'string with line breaks'

Tags: git, git-log

I have the following code in project:

```
someMethodCall();
anotherMethodCall(); //new string
```

I want to find logs, which contains that both srings, with `-S` parameter.
I've tried:

```
git log -S'someMethodCall();anotherMethodCall()'
git log -S'someMethodCall();%nanotherMethodCall()'
git log -S'someMethodCall();\r\nanotherMethodCall()'
git log -S'someMethodCall();\nanotherMethodCall()'
```

...but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git log -S (or -G)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Sltstringgt) does not support an `--and` directive like `git grep` does: see "[Fun with "git log --grep"](http://gitster.livejournal.com/30195.html)" (which is a similar issue)

> "`git log --grep`" is line oriented.
>   That is partly the reason why "`git log`" family does not support `--and` option to begin with.  The `and` semantics is not very useful in the context of "`git log`" command, and this is true even if we limit the discussion to the message part

The [OP Boolean_Type](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695280/boolean-type) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747564/git-log-sstring-with-line-breaks/44753384?noredirect=1#comment76605318_44753384) adding the [`--pickaxe-regex` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---pickaxe-regex):

> Treat the `<string>` given to `-S` as an extended POSIX regular expression to match.

```
git log -S'(anotherMethodCall\(\);)|(someMethodCall\(\);)' --pickaxe-regex
```

Note: if done in a Windows CMD, use double-quotes:

```
git log -S"(anotherMethodCall\(\);)|(someMethodCall\(\);)" --pickaxe-regex
```

From there, a [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-show) can highlight the lines added or deleted.

Comment: You mean: 1) `git log -S'(anotherMethodCall\(\);)|(someMethodCall\(\);)' —pickaxe-regex`; 2) `git show` for every founded commit and search manually in every output needed 2 strings. Right?

Comment: @Boolean_Type True, I forgot about the --pickaxe-regex option. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.